# Concatenate two fields from a JSON Table output

Tags: javascript, json, sql-server

[image]I'm trying to pull details from an API and load to a table in SQL Server. When i created by JSON Table, I gets the output in the below format. My API pulls around 5000 rows in a day.

```
{"fields":["source.time","source.kb_name","source.domain","content.query","content.resultFound","content.articleID","content.articleTitle","content.articleLabels","content.articleContext.Applications","translation.autoTranslated","translation.customersLanguage","translation.originalMessage","channel.rechanneled","channel.channelType","feedback.feedbackType","feedback.feedbackReason","feedback.feedbackText","count.resolved","count.interactions","count.feedback","count.feedbackPositive","count.feedbackNegative"],

rows":[["63725381805336","English","gph.accenture.com","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","True","1518752271","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","Bot","Athena","False","","","False","","","","","1","1","0","0","0"]
["63725381805336","English","gph.accenture.com","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","True","1518752271","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","Bot","Athena","False","","","False","","","","","1","1","0","0","0"],["63725381797070","English","gph.accenture.com","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","True","1518752271","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","Bot","Athena","False","","","False","","","","","1","1","0","0","0"],["63725381797070","English","gph.accenture.com","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","True","1518752271","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","Bot","Athena","False","","","False","","","","","1","1","0","0","0"],["63725381755149","English","gph.accenture.com","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","True","1518752271","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","Bot","Athena","False","","","False","","","","","1","1","0","0","0"],
```

Fields are the Column headers and rows represents the value against each column.

I want to concatenate this in such a form that my output JSON table should be each value in the rows should be prefixed with column header.  for example:

```
rows":[["source.time":"63725381805336","source.kb_name":"English","content.query":"gph.accenture.com" -- etc..
```

Is this possible? I have tried many methods, but of no success. :(

Comment: can plz send the minimal valid JSON format, In your question, the JSON format is incorrect

Comment: Thats way im gettign Anuragh.

{"fields":["source.time","source.kb_name","source.domain","content.query","content.resultFound","content.articleID","content.articleTitle","content.articleLabels","content.articleContext.Applications","translation.autoTranslated","translation.customersLanguage","translation.originalMessage","channel.rechanneled","channel.channelType","feedback.feedbackType","feedback.feedbackReason","feedback.feedbackText","count.resolved","count.interactions","count.feedback","count.feedbackPositive","count.feedbackNegative"],

Comment: rows":[["source.time":"63725381805336","source.kb_name":"English","content.query":"gph.accenture.com","content.resultFound":"Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","True","1518752271","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","Bot","Athena","False","","","False","","","","","1","1","0","0","0"]

Comment: @AnoopKumarKR Please, post your attempts and the SQL Server version. Thanks.

Comment: Here is my attempt.. i cannot provide the api details mentioned in the code. 

`Declare @Object as Int;
DECLARE @hr  int
Declare @json as table(Json_Table nvarchar(max))

Exec @hr=sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0', @Object OUT;
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get',
 'Your Web Service Url (invoked)'
                 'false'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send'
IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Exec @hr=sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @json OUTPUT`

Comment: `IF @hr <> 0 EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object

INSERT into @json (Json_Table) exec sp_OAGetProperty @Object, 'responseText'
-- select the JSON string
select * from @json`

Comment: @AnoopKumarKR You need a dynamic statement, `FOR JSON` is an option to return table as JSON text, but the format is slightly different : `{"rows":[{"source.time":"63725381805336", ..` (array of objects) instead of `{"rows":[["source.time":"63725381805336",` (array of arrays).

Answer (score 0):

With some dynamic sql:

```
declare @json_fields nvarchar(max);
declare @json_rows nvarchar(max);
declare @columns nvarchar(max);
declare @pivot nvarchar(max);
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

declare @json nvarchar(max) = '
{
"fields":["source.time","source.kb_name","source.domain","content.query","content.resultFound","content.articleID","content.articleTitle","content.articleLabels","content.articleContext.Applications","translation.autoTranslated","translation.customersLanguage","translation.originalMessage","channel.rechanneled","channel.channelType","feedback.feedbackType","feedback.feedbackReason","feedback.feedbackText","count.resolved","count.interactions","count.feedback","count.feedbackPositive","count.feedbackNegative"],
"rows":[
    ["63725381805336","English","gph.accenture.com","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","True","1518752271","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","Bot","Athena","False","","","False","","","","","1","1","0","0","0"],
    ["63725381805336","English","gph.accenture.com","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","True","1518752271","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","Bot","Athena","False","","","False","","","","","1","1","0","0","0"],
    ["63725381797070","English","gph.accenture.com","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","True","1518752271","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","Bot","Athena","False","","","False","","","","","1","1","0","0","0"],
    ["63725381797070","English","gph.accenture.com","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","True","1518752271","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","Bot","Athena","False","","","False","","","","","1","1","0","0","0"],
    ["63725381755149","English","gph.accenture.com","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","True","1518752271","Athena Opening Statement with Language Selection","Bot","Athena","False","","","False","","","","","1","1","0","0","0"]
]
}
';

select  @json_fields = case when [key] = 'fields' then [value] else @json_fields end, 
        @json_rows = case when [key] = 'rows' then [value] else @json_rows end
from openjson(@json);

select  @columns = isnull(@columns + ',', '') + '[' + [key] + '] as [' + [value] + ']',
        @pivot = isnull(@pivot + ',', '') + '[' + [key] + ']'
from openjson(@json_fields);

set @sql = '
    SELECT ' + @columns + char(13) + '
    FROM (
        SELECT json_rows.[key] [rows_key], [rows].[key] [fields_key], [rows].[value]
        FROM openjson(@json_rows) json_rows
        CROSS APPLY openjson(json_rows.[value]) [rows]
    ) r
    PIVOT(MAX([value]) FOR [fields_key] in (' + @pivot + ')) p
';

exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@json_rows nvarchar(max)', @json_rows = @json_rows;
```